# I am getting the error' compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

Tags: java, android, android-install-apk

```
Below is my build.gradle
```

its giving me the below error if i generate a signed apk

"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator;"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.funanindou.grocerylist"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//compile 'com.android.zxing:core:3.2.0'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

kindly assist on how i can fix this error

Comment: Within `defaultConfig` try adding this bit of code `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: Its still showing the same error @Ricardo

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are including the `com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded` library twice, could be thet you have also saved a jar of it in your lib folder?

Comment: Thanks @Luca ...I had already saved the jar as a lib. and was also including it as a dependence... Thus commenting out the dependency in build.gradle i was able to generate the apk file.